# Optimizing the O(n^2) algorithm with dictionary, is it possible to go further

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

There are 2 sets:

Set 1 of values(containing all possible values)
Set 2 of values(containing some of the possible values in Set 1)

For each match, we'll indicate in set 1 that we found it.

The O(n^2) way to sort is:

```
foreach(var set1Variable in set1) {
    foreach(var set2Variable in set2) {
        if(set1Variable == set2Variable )
            set1.indexOf(set1Variable).Found = true;
    }
}
```

It is optimizable with a dictionary.

How 'good' or 'bad' is the first solution. What about the dictionary? What should we consider?
What is the optimal way to sort through this and why?

Comment: The goal seems to be to find the intersection of two sets - why is this tagged `sorting`? What data structure is used for the sets?

Comment: You can have O(n), if you put set1 into a hashtable, and iterate on set2, checking every element if it exists in set1.

Comment: If set 1 contains all possible values, then isn't set 3 simply the same as set 2?

Comment: @HeapOverflow  thanks, you're right, there was something about the initial logic about creating a 3rd set. now I'll edit question

Comment: @kaya3 because the potential solutions will definitely include sorting, as is already evident in some answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The proposed solution is `O(n^2)` time with no additional space.
- A dictionary solution (where all elements of the smallest set are
  emplaced into a dictionary) can be `O(n)` / `O(nlogn)` (depending on
  which dictionary, tree based or hash) time and `O(n)` space.
- You can also get `O(nlogn)` time and no additional space, by sorting
  the two containers, and then iterating in parallel to find matching
  items.

Which is better?

Depends on the specific needs and constraints. If you cannot afford the extra space, the dictionary solution becomes none feasible. If `O(nlogn)` time is too much, you should stick with hashing.

---

Appendix: solution 3 (sorting) pseudo code:

```
sort(set1)
sort(set2)

iter1 = set1.iterator()
iter2 = set2.iterator()
while iter1.has_next() and iter2.has_next():
  if iter1.item() == iter2.item():
    set2.add(iter1.item())
    iter1.next()
    iter2.next()
  else if iter1.item() < iter2.item():
    iter1.next()
  else:
    iter2.next()
```

Comment: what kind of extra space would these other solutions demand, roughly? is the first solution considered 'bad' because it's O(n^2)? even though it uses less space? what if we had 100 variables in the set?

Comment: @apaki This is already mentioned in the answer. O(n) for dictionary, very little to no extra space for sorting.

Comment: Yes obviously the dictionary solution is almost no extra space and faster. Still, is the O(n^2) considered 'bad'? How much of a '-' would you consider if you saw somebody use the first solution in their code

Answer (score 2):

You can create a TreeSet and add all sets to it.

```
TreeSet myTreeSet = new TreeSet();
myTreeSet.addAll(myHashSet);
System.out.println(myTreeSet);
```

Assuming your sets are of size n, Space Complexity is O(n) and Time complexity O(nlogn)